# fetch data in map from repository using JPA query

Tags: list, dictionary, jpa, hashmap, fetch

I want to get the data from table using this query:

```
select clientId, Count(countryID) from table groupBy countryID;
```

which gives me the count of `country` corresponding to `clientId`. Normally we fetch into the `List<Object>`.

How i can fecth these details into a `Map<clientId, countryCount>` with `clientId` as key and `countryCount` as value?

Comment: Is it a correct way :-

Comment: @Query("SELECT clientId, COUNT(countryID) from entity GROUP BY countryID")
public Map<Integer,Integer> findCountryCountEntites();